# Is it possible to move the dropped object after drag and drop in android

Tags: android

I am able to drag and drop the button but after dropping the button the dropped button is not moving how to move the dropped button.
i want to move the copy of button image which i droped but i m trying to move after dropping the button but the image of button  which dropped is not possible to move

```
  public class Drop extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
 Button img;
 ImageView image;
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp ;
       @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        img  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             new MarginLayoutParams(

                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        img.setOnTouchListener(this);
        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.vg);

 }
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
         int x1 = (int)me.getX();
         int y1 = (int)me.getY();
        image = new ImageView(this);
         image.setImageBitmap(img.getDrawingCache());
                layout.addView(image,lp);
        if(v==image)
        {

         lp.setMargins(x1, y1, 0, 0);
         image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
         image.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    }
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {


    } 

    else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
         int x1 = (int)me.getX();
         int y1 = (int)me.getY();
image.setPadding((int) me.getRawX(), (int) me.getRawY(), 0, 0);
            image.invalidate();

            if(v==image)
            {
             lp.setMargins(x1, y1, 0, 0);
             image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
             image.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        }

    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Look at the launcher code of how views are moved. Following this example, it should be possible.